# Show recent items in general, but not with specific programs, on Windows 7 start menu

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

In Windows 7, there is a "Recent Items" list on the start menu.  It contains links to recently opened documents and is essentially the same as "My Recent Documents" in Windows XP.

However, Windows 7 also shows recent documents corresponding to the particular programs on the start menu.

I would like to *retain* the "Recent Items" list but ***disable*** the display of recent documents corresponding to all the programs on the start menu.  **How can I do this?**

Here is a minimal example of what I would like:

[image: Excel]

[image: Word]

[image: Recent Items]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying an alternative Start Menu like Classic Shell™ http://www.classicshell.net

The option you're looking for is "Enable jumplists". You can find it in the "Main Menu" tab, in the Settings window. Just clear the checkbox and you're done.

[image: Settings for Classic Start Menu]

---

It also has other many advanced features and improvements over the standard Start Menu:

- Drag and drop to let you organize your applications
- Options to show Favorites, expand Control Panel, etc
- Shows recently used documents. The number of documents to display is
  customizable
- Translated in 40 languages, including Right-to-left support for
  Arabic and Hebrew
- Does not disable the original start menu in Windows. You can access
  it by Shift+Click on the start button
- Right-click on an item in the menu to delete, rename, sort, or
  perform other tasks
- The search box helps you find your programs without getting in the
  way of your keyboard shortcuts
- Supports jumplists for easy access to recent documents and common
  tasks
- Available for 32 and 64-bit operating systems
- Has support for skins, including additional 3rd party skins
- Fully customizable in both looks and functionality
- Support for Microsoft’s Active Accessibility
- Converts the “All Programs” button in the Windows menu into a
  cascading menu (Windows 7)
- Implements a customizable Start button
- Can show, search and launch Windows Store apps (Windows 8 and up)
- And last but not least – it's FREE!